# Default value for LAG function in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to build a view which allows me to track the difference between paid values at two consecutive month_ids. When a figure is missing however, that would be because it's the first entry and therefore has a paid amount of 0. At present, I'm using the below to represent the previous figure since the `[,default]` argument has not been implemented in MariaDB.

```
CASE WHEN (
    NOT(policy_agent_month.policy_agent_month_id IS NOT NULL        
    AND LAG(days_paid, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id ) IS NULL)) THEN        
         LAG(days_paid, 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id)        
    ELSE 
         0        
    END
```

The problem I have with this is that I have about 30 variables which this function needs to be applied over and it makes my code unreadable and very clunky. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Default for LAG() and LEAD() for that matter is always 1 record "back" or "forward"... `LAG(<column>)` and `LAG(<column>, 1)` mean the same things.

Comment: The 'default' argument in other versions of SQL refers to handling NULL values. I'm not struggling with the 'distance' at present.

Comment: Because of the title it seams you had "issues" with it or a question about it.. i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)  then.

Comment: "The 'default' argument in other versions of SQL refers to handling NULL values" What is wrong with @TheImpaler 's answer because it seams to be a valid workaround to this "default" value you are after.

Comment: Doesn't look like anything's wrong with it. I'm just working on implementation first before I commit to it.

Comment: "before I commit to it. " if you don't want to directly commit whats stopping you from sharing example data and expected results maybe you get more solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) in MariaDB 10.2+ to pre-compute frequently used expressions and name them for later use:

```
with
x as ( -- first we compute the CTE that we name "x"
  select
    *,
    coalesce(
      LAG(days_paid, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id), 
      123456
    ) as prev_month -- this expression gets the name "prev_month"
  from my_table -- or a simple/complex join here
)
select -- now the main query
  prev_month
from x
... -- rest of your query here where "prev_month" is computed.
```

In the main query `prev_month` has the lag value, or the default value `123456` when it's null.

Answer (score 2):

Why use `WITH`?

```
SELECT province, tot_pop,
       tot_pop - COALESCE(
              (LAG(tot_pop) OVER (ORDER BY tot_pop ASC)),
                        0) AS delta
    FROM provinces
    ORDER BY tot_pop asc;

+---------------------------+----------+---------+
| province                  | tot_pop  | delta   |
+---------------------------+----------+---------+
| Nunavut                   |    14585 |   14585 |
| Yukon                     |    21304 |    6719 |
| Northwest Territories     |    24571 |    3267 |
| Prince Edward Island      |    63071 |   38500 |
| Newfoundland and Labrador |   100761 |   37690 |
| New Brunswick             |   332715 |  231954 |
| Nova Scotia               |   471284 |  138569 |
| Saskatchewan              |   622467 |  151183 |
| Manitoba                  |   772672 |  150205 |
| Alberta                   |  2481213 | 1708541 |
| British Columbia          |  3287519 |  806306 |
| Quebec                    |  5321098 | 2033579 |
| Ontario                   | 10071458 | 4750360 |
+---------------------------+----------+---------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, it is not cheap (at least in MySQL 8.0);
the table has 13 rows, yet

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
MySQL 8.0:
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_read_rnd           | 89    |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 52    |
| Handler_write              | 26    |
  (and others)

MariaDB 10.3:
| Handler_read_rnd           | 77    |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 42    |
| Handler_tmp_write          | 13    |
| Handler_update             | 13    |
```